# GDB breakpoints

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I have a list of breakpoints which I want to add each time I debug a particular program.

Is there a way I can put all of the breakpoint information in a file and use it at the start of each debug session? In other words can I **provide a script file with breakpoint information to GDB before I give the 'run' command?**

Answer (score 33):

From **man gdb(1)**:

```
  -x file
           Execute GDB commands from file file.
```

You could then put your breakpoints in a file:

```
break [file:]function
break [file:]function
...
```

Answer (score 31):

You can put all of the commands you want into a `.gdbinit` file that lives in the same directory as the executable you are debugging.

Something like:

```
b somefile.c:128
b otherfile.c:33
```

Should work just fine.

Yes, the `-x` command line argument will allow you to execute arbitrary files at GDB startup, but maintaining a `.gdbinit` file for each project means that the file is executed automatically (without the need to specify a filename).  Also, you can easily add the project-specific `.gdbinit` file to your source control, which means that all of your team members can use the same debugging facilities.

Answer (score 13):

Besides using an external file, you can also just keep GDB open: If the binary under GDB changes, it will reload the binary and libraries without losing your breakpoints the next time you run.

Answer (score 10):

The *[save breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Save-Breakpoints.html)* command is new as of GDB 7.2 (2011-08-23). After you've saved the breakpoints to a file you can read them into a later GDB session using the *[source](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html)* command and then the next time you run GDB you can use the `-x <filename>` option.

```
save breakpoints <filename>
  Save all current breakpoint definitions to a file suitable for use
  in a later debugging session.  To read the saved breakpoint
  definitions, use the `source' command.
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use:

```
gdb --command=commands.gdb ./a.out
```

where `commands.gdb` is a text file with your breakpoints.

`--command` is probably the same as `-x`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of GDB claims that the commands "[save breakpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Save-Breakpoints.html#Save-Breakpoints)" and "[source](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html)" can be used.

However, this doesn't work on my GDB ([Ubuntu 7.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_7.10_(Gutsy_Gibbon)) (Gutsy Gibbon)).

Comment: I had the same version and it wasn't working. I found out that this feature is added with gdb version 7.2. If you compile the newer version it works.