# Getting GDB to save a list of breakpoints

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

OK, *[info break](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html)* lists the breakpoints, but not in a format that would work well with reusing them using the --command [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500967/gdb-breakpoints). Does GDB have a method for dumping them into a file acceptable for input again?  Sometimes in a debugging session, it is necessary to restart GDB after building up a set of breakpoints for testing.

The .gdbinit file has the same problem as --command. The *info break* command does not list commands, but rather a table for human consumption.

To elaborate, here is a sample from *info break*:

```
(gdb) info break
Num Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1   breakpoint     keep y   0x08048517 <foo::bar(void)+7>
```

Answer (score 238, accepted):

As of GDB 7.2 (2011-08-23) you can now use the *[save breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Save-Breakpoints.html)* command.

```
save breakpoints <filename>
  Save all current breakpoint definitions to a file suitable for use
  in a later debugging session.  To read the saved breakpoint
  definitions, use the `source' command.
```

Use [`source <filename>`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html) to restore the saved breakpoints from the file.

Comment: what about if they are from a shared lib load? It answers N by default it seems... `Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]`

Comment: @bjackfly use `set breakpoint pending on` as described in [how to answer Y in gdb script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356138/how-to-answer-y-in-gdb-script) and [gdb: how to set breakpoints on future shared libraries with a --command flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100444/gdb-how-to-set-breakpoints-on-future-shared-libraries-with-a-command-flag)

Comment: Note that when you have a breakpoint condition which cannot be resolved at startup (`break g_log if log_level==G_LOG_LEVEL_CRITICAL`), then at least gdb 7.8.1 will stop parsing further commands. If you have additional commands which should be executed for that breakpoint, put the `commands` line before the `condition` line.

Comment: @Andry I rolled back your edit to my original blockquote because the text is a verbatim quote from the documentation... I would otherwise agree with your edit if it were my own words instead.

Comment: @aculich: I see. I would recommend to use the quoting style rather than the code style in any case.

Comment: The .gdbinit does not work with 'cgdb' so I am fine with the explicit 'save breakpoints /tmp/pointbreak.dbg' and it's opposite 'source /tmp/pointbreak.dbg'

Answer (score 27):

***This answer is outdated. GDB now supports saving directly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3984156/331858).***

You can use logging:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8049329
(gdb) info break
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x08049329 <main+16>
(gdb) set logging file breaks.txt
(gdb) set logging on
Copying output to breaks.txt.
(gdb) info break
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x08049329 <main+16>
(gdb) q
```

The file breaks.txt now contains:

```
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x08049329 <main+16>
```

Writing an AWK script that transforms that into a format useful for the `.gdbinit` or a `--command` file is easy. Or you may even make the script emit separate `--eval-command`'s to the GDB command line...

Adding this small macro to [.gdbinit](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html) will help you do it:

```
# Call with dump_breaks file.txt
define dump_breaks
    set logging file $arg0
    set logging redirect on
    set logging on
    info breakpoints
    set logging off
    set logging redirect off
end
```

Comment: One could just as easily use cut-and-paste, but the scripting method seems to be the way to go.

Comment: i don't think cut-and-paste is easier than just writing a script once, then using it every time again :) after all, that was the very reason you asked this question in the first place, i think :)

Comment: Um, I meant use cut-and-paste instead of the logging method.  Scripting is it so far for sure.

Comment: wow! gdb fail!  I use it everyday and love many of its features.  But lack is just plain dumb.

Comment: This answer is now over 2 years old so it may be obsolete if you are using a newer version of gdb. As of gdb 7.2 you can now use the `save breakpoints` command.

Comment: This answer is still useful to those of us who need to work with legacy systems.

Answer (score 11):

Put your GDB commands and breakpoints in a [.gdbinit file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html) just as you might type them at the `gdb>` prompt, and GDB will automatically load and run them on startup. This is a per-directory file, so you can have different files for different projects.

Comment: This actually fails to work, I get "warning: save-tracepoints: no tracepoints to save.'  This despite breakpoints being set.  Using gdb 6.8.

Comment: This works for me. GDB needs the presence of a global .gdbinit in your $HOME/.gdbinit with content  'add-auto-load-safe-path /home/johnny/src/.gdbinit'  and thus the src/ folder has also a separate .gdbinit

Answer (score 9):

An extension to [anon's extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501486/getting-gdb-to-save-a-list-of-breakpoints/2233182#2233182) to [Johannes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501486/getting-gdb-to-save-a-list-of-breakpoints/501530#501530):

```
.gdbinit:

define bsave
    shell rm -f brestore.txt
    set logging file brestore.txt
    set logging on
    info break
    set logging off
    # Reformat on-the-fly to a valid GDB command file
    shell perl -n -e 'print "break $1\n" if /^\d+.+?(\S+)$/g' brestore.txt > brestore.gdb
end
document bsave
  store actual breakpoints
end

define brestore
  source brestore.gdb
end
document brestore
  restore breakpoints saved by bsave
end
```

With `brestore` you can then restore the breakpoints saved with `bsave`.

Comment: Here's a better regex : perl -ne "print \"break \$1 \n\" if /at\s(.*:\d+)/" brestore.txt

Answer (score 6):

Extension to [the answer from Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501486/getting-gdb-to-save-a-list-of-breakpoints/501530#501530): you could automatically reformat the output of `info break` into a valid GDB command file:

```
.gdbinit:

define bsave
   shell rm -f brestore.txt
   set logging file brestore.txt
   set logging on
   info break
   set logging off
   # Reformat on-the-fly to a valid gdb command file
   shell perl -n -e 'print "break $1\n" if /^\d+.+?(\S+)$/g' brestore.txt > brestore.gdb
end
document bsave
  store actual breakpoints
end
```

Afterwards you have a valid commandfile in `brestore.gdb`.

This worked for me when the application is compiled with `-g`.

I also successfully tested it with GDB v6.8 on [Ubuntu 9.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_9.10_.28Karmic_Koala.29) (Karmic Koala).

Comment: Thank you for this snippet!  Works great. Successfully tested with GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-966) in CarbonEmacs GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.6.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0) on Mac OS 10.5.8.

Answer (score 5):

Put the following in [~/.gdbinit](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html) to define *bsave* and *brestore* as GDB commands to save- and restore breakpoints.

```
define bsave
    save breakpoints ~/.breakpoints
end

define brestore
   source ~/.breakpoints
end
```

Comment: Probably makes sense to save these per project, one global break points state file might get messy.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this:

[`save breakpoints [filename]`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Save-Breakpoints.html)

Comment: This has already been covered in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501486/getting-gdb-to-save-a-list-of-breakpoints/3984156#3984156).

Answer (score 3):

I found the following addition to a previous answer useful to save/load the breakpoints to a specific file.

- Save breakpoints: bsave {filename}
- Load breakpoints: bload {filename}

As in the previous answer, add the following code to the file ~/.gdbinit

```
# Save breakpoints to a file
define bsave
    if $argc != 1
        help bsave
    else
    save breakpoints $arg0
    end
end
document bsave
Saves all current defined breakpoints to the defined file in the PWD
Usage: bsave <filename>
end

# Loads breakpoints from a file
define bload
    if $argc != 1
        help bload
    else
        source $arg0
    end
end
document bload
Loads all breakpoints from the defined file in the PWD
Usage: bload <filename>
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> warning: Current output protocol does
>   not support redirection

I also get this error/warning in GDB when trying to enable logging in [TUI](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html) mode. However, the logging seems to work when in "non-TUI" mode. So I leave TUI mode whenever I want to log something. (Toggle back and forth into TUI mode with **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>**, **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>**).

Here's how I work:

1. start GDB (in normal mode)
2. enable logging: `set logging on` - now it should not complain.
3. toggle back/forth to TUI mode and do GDB stuff
4. whenever I want to log something (like a huge backtrace dump) - toggle to normal mode

Comment: Oh, and if you like using "screen" (like I do) it will get a bit messy, since it uses the same hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that setting a breakpoint is context sensitive.
What if you have two static functions named *foo*?

If you are already debugging one of the modules that defines foo, then 
GDB will assume you meant that one. But if you just dump "break foo" into a file and then read that file at start-up, it will not be clear which function *foo* you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Any other ideas? I have got

```
warning: Current output protocol does not support redirection
```

after

```
set logging on
```

**EDIT:**

I know that question is "how to save a list of breakpoints", however I just discovered, that with GDB we can simply set "saved in file" breakpoints by

```
gdb> source breakpoints.txt
```

where `breakpoints.txt` is a file like this:

```
break main.cpp:25
break engine.cpp:465
break wheel.cpp:57
```