# How can save breakpoint setting in linux consol while debugging a c++ program

Tags: gdb

I am now using linux developing c++ program. the workbench is windows connecting linux workstation console through putty.  I set lot of breakpoint in the program, using gdb to debug program is very powerful:)  But I do not no how to save breakpoint, so the next time when "gdb ./MyProg" the breakpoint information is lost，“info  breakpoint” show no breakpoint,  It puzzled me lot of day. Can anybody give some advice? Thanks first.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Getting gdb to save a list of breakpoints?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/501486/2509).

Comment: yew,  I have found it, thanks the same. noisy's answer inthe link up works well:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting gdb to save a list of breakpoints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501486/getting-gdb-to-save-a-list-of-breakpoints)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [GDB Manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Save-Breakpoints.html), you can use the command:

```
save breakpoints <file>
```

To save them to , and then:

```
source <file>
```

To load them.

If the break points are not yet loaded, you may want to tell gdb to allow loading those breakpoints later.

```
set breakpoint pending on
```

Comment: but when I set the breakpoints and save breakpoints, system echoed with " warning: save-tracepoints: no tracepoints to save" why even I have set and hit the breakpoints? and what is the tracepoint means? thans for your help first!

Comment: sounds like first entering "set logging on" then can use " source <file> " to  load the breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

On similar lines,

you can log all gdb inputs into a file and can see.

You can enable log using 'set logging on [filename]'. If file name is not mentioned, then default filename - gdb.txt is taken.

Debug Log might be useful when you want to share gdb trace details

If you do not want to log, disable log using 'set logging off'

--Cheers