# Save breakpoints in LLDB

Tags: debugging, llvm, lldb

How can I save breakpoints in lldb? This is a feature that gdb has and I suspect that lldb has it too but I haven't been able to find it in the help.

How this is done in gdb:

[Getting gdb to save a list of breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501486/getting-gdb-to-save-a-list-of-breakpoints)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Jim Ingham said above, you currently cannot save breakpoints in lldb. However, there is a work around. You can load lldb commands from a command file as follows:

```
lldb -S <path_to_command_file>
```

You can have this in your command file:

```
file <path_to_binary>
breakpoint set --file file0.cc --line 22
breakpoint set --file file1.cc --line 237
```

The above command file will load the binary and set the breakpoints when lldb starts.

Answer (score 26):

You can you use `breakpoint write` to save current breakpoints to a file by using

`breakpoint write -f debug`

This saves your breakpoints to file 'debug'. However the saved breakpoints are not in a simple format compared to that of gdb.

You can read this file with `breakpoint read -f debug` when you start `lldb`.

The file is stored as a JSON, so you can read it in your text editor of choice. You can put the file wherever you want so instead of `debug`, you could do use `~/Desktop/myFilename.json`

Comment: This works, and as it's both newer and more effective than the accepted answer, it deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible.