# Is it possible to 'set print thread-events off' from the command-line arguments when invoking gdb?

Tags: linux, debugging, command-line, gdb, alias

Every time I start gdb, I immediately do:

```
set print thread-events off
```

It would be nice if I could do this from the command-line arguments, so that I could just set up an alias instead of re-typing it every time.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a gdb startup script?  Create `~/.gdbinit` with the commands to be executed when it starts.

A `.gdbinit` [can also be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500975/198536) in the directory you are in when executing the program.

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

```
gdb -ex "set print thread-events off" ...other-args...
```

Comment: This is the most direct answer to my question, and I up-voted it, but wallyk's answer is the best solution to my problem.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Nevermind, turned out my command was being interpolated incorrectly. Just changed `cmd='gdb -q -batch -ex "set print thread-events off" -ex run...'; $cmd` to `cmd=(gdb -q -batch -ex "set print thread-events off" -ex run...); "$cmd[@]"`